# Windows phone maps control how to add layers and pushpin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, maps, controls

What is the equivalent to adding pushpins and layers to the native windows 8 maps control. At the moment I am using Bing maps, but I want to use the windows 8 native maps control:

```
img_layer = new MapLayer(); 
map.Children.Add(img_layer); //not working for windows phone 8 maps
pushpin.Template = (ControlTemplate)(this.Resources["PushpinControlTemplate1"]);
map.Children.Add(pushpin); //not working for windows phone 8 maps
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's how to add an overlay to the map control... The following is just the important sections from the MSDN documentation: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207037(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207037%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

First up, create the overlay.

```
//Creating a MapOverlay and associating the content with some UI.
MapOverlay myOverlay = new MapOverlay();
myOverlay.Content = /* Set this value to a UIElement. In your case, some custom PushPin UI */;
myOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(47.6097, -122.3331);
```

Alright, now you have an overlay. Next, create a `MapLayer` and add your overlay to it. The `MapLayer` is what gets added to the map control - not the overlay itself.

```
//Creating a MapLayer and adding the MapOverlay to it
MapLayer myLayer = new MapLayer();
myLayer.Add(myOverlay);
MyMap.Layers.Add(myLayer);
```

That's how to use overlays!

With that being said, if you don't want to roll your own pushpin UI, the WP8 toolkit provides this functionality. 
http://phone.codeplex.com/

You'll need some more instruction on how to actually use that though... This blog seems to explain the toolkit functionality well: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/maps-in-windows-phone-8-and-phone-toolkit-a-winning-team-part-2/